# How to Save a Generated XSD File

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xsd

I have some code (in c#) that creates a bunch of XML sheets on the fly. At the end of my code I am generating XSDs based on those XML sheets. I am making the XSDs successfully, but saving them as files is what I cannot figure out. My code so far is basically taken from the MSDN page on generating XSDs from XML sheets:

```
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
        string[] directoryFiles = Directory.GetFiles(xmlFilePath);

        foreach (string xFile in directoryFiles)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(xFile);
            XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
            XmlSchemaInference schema = new XmlSchemaInference();

            schema.TypeInference = XmlSchemaInference.InferenceOption.Relaxed;

            schemaSet = schema.InferSchema(reader);

            //insert code here to save the file
            //stored in schemaSet.Schemas()
        }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you just want to produce an XSD file from an XML file, you can use Microsoft's [XSD.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx), which is included with Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't you have to run that from the command line manually? This code will be run on a schedule, and I need these XSDs to be generated each time dynamically.

Comment: You're right, this is run from Visual Studio command line. However, [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/41732z18(v=vs.110).aspx) may help if you want to generate them dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XMLSchemaSet has a method called Schemas() that returns a collection of all the schemas in the set. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142fs5cx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a page that describes how to access these.

Simply access each Schema in the set using the code in the link above and write it using the example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04x694fe%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).